# How to reset the database to a known state at the beginning of a class of Codeception tests?

Tags: database, codeception

We're using the '\Codeception\TestCase\Test' class for tests, and reloading the database in a '_before' method works fine. But we would prefer to only load it once per test class rather than reload it for each test method.

How do I load a different dump file at the beginning of each test *class*?

More detail:

We're testing a batch import into a MySQL database that has several stages:
1. Upload one or more CSV file(s) to an import service API and verify
2. Import into database
3. Run several services on the imported data
4. Export the resulting data back to CSV

At each testing stage we would like to be able to put the initial state of the database into the resulting state of the previous testing stage. We have helpers to save and load the database on-the-fly from a dump file.

Answer (score 0):

there is tool called Respawn https://github.com/jbogard/respawn . I am not sure if it supports MySQL.